# 'pygame.Rect' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Code:

```
import pygame , sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *

def enemie():
    global speed, ball
    ball.y += speed
    if ball.y == 602:
        ball = pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, 450), 0 ,20,20)

def blast():
    global bl, blast
    blast.y = bl


def player_animation():
    global player_speed, playerx
    player.x = player_speed



pygame.init()
running = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

speed = 7
bl = 1
player_speed = 1



ball = pygame.Rect(random.randint(0, 450), 0 ,20,20)
player = pygame.Rect(250, 450, 50, 50)
blast = pygame.Rect(300, 0 ,20,20)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))


while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
    enemie()
    player_animation()
    blast()
  
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255)) #color

    
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, [255, 0, 0], ball)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, [0, 0, 255], player)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen, [0, 255, 0], blast)
    
    if ball.colliderect(player):
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
        

    keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_LEFT] and player.x !=  -4 :
        player_speed -= 5

    if keys[K_RIGHT] and player.x !=  451:
        player_speed += 5

    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        bl += 5
    pygame.display.flip()
    
    clock.tick(30)
pygame.quit()
```

error:

```
line 54, in <module>
    blast()
TypeError: 'pygame.Rect' object is not callable
```

I am trying to create some balls that move. and the green ball or blast is supposed to move when I click,
Does the error mean that there is a ) or a ( that doesn't belong? But I can't find my mistake... I've had this error before and I  can't remember how I solved it. what does the error mean? and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your global `blast` variable [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the `blast` function.  By the time you call `blast()`, `blast` is no longer defined as a function, but is a `pygame.Rect` instead.  The error is telling you that you can't call a `Rect` like a function.

Change the name of one of them so they don't collide.